# Center logo dynamically in menu

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, center

I want that the logo stays in the middle of menu items in the navigation, that it seems like the logo "splits" the navigation like in [this example](http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/HyLdg). It is important, that the logo stays also in the middle of page. So the menu items are arround them but the logo is "fixed".

I add a sepeartor div dynamically with javascript to the middle of menu items (when six items, the seperator stays after the third) to create the effect I discribe above.

```
.seperator {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 10px;
 margin-left: 69px;
 margin-right: 206px;
 width: 10px;
}
```

But when the editor adds a new menu item to the navigation or renames an item (CMS), the logo is not centered anymore. With fixed margin it will not work but I don't know how to calculate dynamically the width or margin size. I want to add the value via javascript. I think this is the only way it could work.

So I need a script or a helpful idea to do this.

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you please elaborate, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I edit my question. I hope now it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I tried a few things and I don't wanted to use two navigations but I did:

```
<div class="inner">
 <div class="desktop_navi">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>             
 </div>            
 <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img width="281" height="280" src=""></a></div>   
 <div class="desktop_navi">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li> 
  </ul>             
 </div>    
</div>
```

Thats my new HTML-Markup. Here the style I use:

```
.inner {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner .desktop_navi,.logo {
  display: table-cell;
}
.inner .desktop_navi {
  text-align: left;
}
.header .inner .desktop_navi:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

This is not the best solution, but it works, is responsive and there are no problems with older browsers. If anyone finds a realy good solution with a single navigation, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Responsive solution, bare HTML & CSS:

```
<div class="navBar">
    <table class="menu">
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <table class="nested" >
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">first</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">second</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2mob6nb.png" alt="Michigan State" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
                <table class="nested" >
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">third</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">fourth</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">fifth</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<style>
    .navBar {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .menu {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu .logo {
        width: 22%;
    }
    .menu .logo img {
        width: 200px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .left, .right {
        width: 39%;
    }
    .nested {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .nested td {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJQpXG)

Comment: "How do you center the logo when there are only 5 normal list items..or any odd number" is what the OP seems to be asking. You solution doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: Logo cannot be the center among odd number of equal width items. There should be even number.  Example:    -- -- *** -- -- --   stars will never be in the center. Centered logo supposes the same number on it's left as on it's right. Otherwise it doesn't look good.

Comment: Tell that to the OP...it's what he wants.

Comment: It is realy hard to describe what I want, I edit my post again, but here the "new" fact: It is important, that the logo stays also in the middle of page. So the menu items are arround them but the logo is "fixed". Your html doesn't help me with this, because the logo-list item will not stay in middle of navigation and in the middle of page. Sorry that I missed that in my post!

Comment: @Lunokhod It doesn't matter if it looks good in our oppinion, that's what my client wants, so I need to do that.

Comment: @ReAlPeNx I changed my answer, hopefully I understand what you need. You can use tables and absolute positioning of the whole menu. If you will add items on both sides, logo will stay in the center and menu items will adjust automatically.

Comment: Added solution for menu with NOT equal number of items. Nested tables are used.

Comment: I create a "modern" website, so with table and fixed width the navigation is not responsive. When I want a solution like yours I could set a fixed width for every menu item and could calculate the positioning with javascript. So thats why I am looking for a script, because I think it is not possible with only css and html.

Comment: See responsive solution.

Answer (score -1):

flex box might work for this.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/